# Adding Values in Shell with awk

Tags: shell, curl, awk

I'm trying to average out the load time for a website using cURL in shell. I am able to save the `%{time_total}` to a variable in shell using the following code:

```
result=$(curl -o /dev/null  -s -w "%{time_total}\n" "$url")
```

In this example, `$result` has values like `.013`, `.035`, and `.024`. I want to add these together so that I can average them off. I tried to use awk in various manners to do the arithmetic buy am just not able to get it. I've tried things like:

```
sum=`ps -ef | awk '/port 10 \-/ {print $result+$sum}'`
```

and

```
sum=$(awk 'BEGIN{s=$result+$sum} END {print s}' /dev/null)
```

and

```
sum=$(awk '{print $result+$sum}')
```

Each of these just don't work in one way or another. Here is my full script that will output each load time from the cURL. Any help to get the total time and average would be hugely appreciated.

```
#!/bin/sh

while getopts ":u:c:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    u) url="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    c) count="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    \?) echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG" >&2
    ;;
  esac
done

printf "Load Testing: %s\n" "$url"
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"

declare -i sum=0
for ((i=0; i<count; i++)); do
    result=$(curl -o /dev/null  -s -w "%{time_total}\n" "$url")
    echo "$result"
done

echo "$sum"
```

Comment: how about sum = $(echo "$result+$sum" | bc)

Comment: that's not standard `sh` syntax - would work in `bash` though.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to sum values that are real value in nature you can use `bc -l` with a simple echo statement.

It is basically used for performing arithmetic operations with floating point precision.

Simply add the following line in the for loop

```
sum="$(echo "$result+$sum" | bc -l)"
```

This will add the result value to the sum variable. After this you can divide the sum to get the required average.

Comment: You may as well make the average calc explicit: `avg="$(echo "$sum / $count" | bc -l)"`. Just make sure count is non-zero or skip the calculation if/when it is.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out, have to store the initial value of `sum` with a simple `sum=0` instead of declaring it, then you have to save and store the value with:

```
sum=$(echo $s | awk "{print (($result+$sum))}")
```

Comment: Why are you piping `$s` into awk?

Comment: That is an extremely wacky "solution". Do not do that, it's opening you up to ALL sorts of issues given various values of variables, contents of the directory you are executing from, etc. Delete this before it starts accumulating downvotes.